# Can I use the Sample.split function to split data while filtering based on certain fields?

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am using the sample.split function in R from the caTools package to split my data to training and test data for cross validation.  However I need to split my data in such a way that the test data  is targeted.  This is part of a flight risk model and I need my test data to be geared towards certain grades and locations and not just a random split of the data only preserving the ratio between who stayed and left.

spl <- sample.split(data$Voluntary, 3/4)

train <- data[spl,]

test <- data[!spl,]

This code splits my data into 75% training and 25% testing.  But I want the testing to only include data$grade = "G4", "G5", and "G6" and data$location = "Houston".  Is there a way to build that into my code?

Comment: Does the ratio of `Houston/G4/G5/etc.` values in your training set matter? I.e., are you only concerned with filtering the test data *after* performing the split?

Comment: I'd like the split to be focused on just those items.  If I do the filter after the split, then I lose a lot of data that was part of the split and I don't want to loose out on that information.   I'd like to do the filter as PART of the split if possible